# Why is the badge showing build failed when the most recent builds have passed

Tags: travis-ci

My project is showing a "Build failed" badge, but the builds are passing:

https://travis-ci.org/aexmachina/ember-notify/builds

Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue, and don't seem to find the problem.